# jquery mobile: add event handler to page dialog close button

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, dialog

Open a page in dialog style, the close button is added by default. Is there a way to catch the click event of the close button of the dialog page. I like to invoke a callback before the dialog page is closed.

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="true" >
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        This is Page1.

        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" onclick="showDialog();">Show Dialog</a>

    </div>

    <script>
        function showDialog() {
            $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#page2", { role: "dialog" } );

        }
   </script>

</div>


<div data-role="page" id="page2">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="true" >
        <h1>Dialog</h1>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

        This is Dialog
    </div>
</div>
```

The pagecontainerhide event can be used. but it did not work for ajax. If the dialog page is dynamically created in DOM, the ui.prevPage is not defined for the hide event.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close button is an anchor tag (`<a></a>`) in side a header element with class .ui-header inside a dialog container with class ui-dialog-contain. So you can use the jQuery selector:

```
".ui-dialog-contain .ui-header a"
```

When you handle the click event, you can get the parent page by finding the **[closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** DOM element with the ui-dialog class:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){

    $(document).on("click", ".ui-dialog-contain .ui-header a", function(e){
        alert("close dialog: " + $(this).closest(".ui-dialog").prop("id"));       
    });

});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/14b064jz/2/)**